# Cannot create box-shadow of a SVG polygon at the bottom only by css

Tags: css, reactjs, polygon

The code is part of a reactJS project. The polygon of SVG is as below:

```
return ( <div>
        <svg width={this.state.width} height={this.state.height} viewBox={"0 0 "+this.state.width+" "+this.state.height} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path onClick={e=>this.getMenu(e)} d={"M "+this.state.width/2+" 0 l -10 20 l 20 0 z"} stroke="green" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
        <path d={"M "+this.state.width/2+" 0 l -10 20 l 20 0 z"} stroke="green" stroke-width="3" fill="none" transform={"rotate(180 "+this.state.width/2+" "+10+")"}/>
        <polygon points={this.state.polygon1} stroke="none" stroke-width="10" fill="#BBB" opacity="0.8"/>
        <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad" x2="0" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#BBB"/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFF"/>
        </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <polygon className="curtain" points={this.state.polygon}/>
        </svg>
    </div> );
```

And the corresponding CSS is as follows:

```
.curtain{
  margin-top: 1em;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: aliceblue;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px gray;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px gray;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px gray;
  fill: url(#grad);
}
```

And the result is as follows:
[image]

But the box-shadow doesn't work while other attributes of css are serving fine. Can someone please help in this regard pointing the error?

Comment: Please create a ReactJS demo for the code. You can use Codesandbox or Stackblitz.

Comment: @m4n0, okay, the demo is at https://react-uk9me9.stackblitz.io/, please help me find why box-shadow isn't working

Comment: `box-shadow` won't work on it: https://nimb.ws/9gvMHb Only those properties are allowed on `polygon`